# Two random variables with the same distributions

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

Here's a simple question.

Suppose that random variables $X$ and $Y$ have the same distributions with 
$\mathbb{E}|X| = \mathbb{E} |Y| < \infty$.

Assume that sgn$(X-c)$ = sgn$(Y-c)$, almost surely for any constant $c$.

Then is it true that $X=Y$ almost surely?

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Note that

$$\int |X-Y| \, dP = \int_{\{X>Y\}} (X-Y) \, dP + \int_{\{Y>X\}} (Y-X) \, dP.$$

Since $\{\omega : X(\omega) > Y(\omega)\} = \bigcup_{q \in \mathbb{Q}} \{\omega : X(\omega) > q > Y(\omega)\},$ we can see that

$$\int_{\{X>Y\}} (X-Y) \, dP = \int_{\cup_{q \in \mathbb{Q}} \{\omega : X(\omega) > q > Y(\omega)\}} (X-Y) \, dP
 \leq \sum_{q \in \mathbb{Q}} \int_{\{\omega : X(\omega) > q > Y(\omega)\} } (X-Y) \, dP.$$

However, $\{\omega:X(\omega)>q>Y(\omega)\}$ has probability $0$ for each $q \in \mathbb{Q}$ by our assumption.

This implies that $\int_{\{X>Y\}} (X-Y) \, dP = 0$.

A very similar argument shows that $\int_{\{Y>X\} } (Y-X) \, dP =0$, hence we obtain $\int |X-Y| \, dP = 0$.

We're done.

Answer (score 0):

Divide the space into two parts $A=\{w|X(w)>Y(w)\}$ and $B=\{w|X(w)<Y(w)\}$. Then on both $A$ and $B$ use BIG AGNES's argument to conclude the result as we can choose a single constant c for both the sets $A$ and $B$.